# Laravel 5.7 exists/unique validation with JSON field type

Tags: json, laravel, validation, unique, exists

I have a "countries" table with the following fields:

```
id: integer
name: json
```

Field "name" stores value as:

```
{ "en": "Germany", "de": "Deutschland" }
```

I wrote the following rule:

```
'country' => 'nullable|string|max:255|exists:countries,name->en'
```

but it doesn't work like that. How do I make it work?

MariaDB 10.1.36 / Laravel 5.7

Comment: Is there an error? What database and version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I added information. Thank you.

Comment: Laravel doesn't support JSON queries on MariaDB. This will be fixed Laravel 5.8.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use this package: https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb

Comment: I upgraded MariaDB to 10.3.9 and installed package laravel-mariadb. All now working like a charm. If you want, you may post your two previous comments as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 5.7 doesn't support JSON queries on MariaDB. This will be fixed in Laravel 5.8.

In the meantime, you can use this package: https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible with the default validation rules from laravel.
You would have to add a where clause to the exists rule or create your own [custom validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules)  rule for this:

**Using where clause:**

```
public function rules()
{
    $country = $this->country;

    return [
        'country' => [
            'nullable',
            'string',
            'max:255',
            Rule::exists('countries')->where(function ($query) use ($country) {
                return $query->where(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(`name`, "$.en")'), $country);
            })
        ],
    ];
}
```